# Make a table-cell round and responsive?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I know only basic stuff when it comes to HTML and CSS, so please forgive me if my question is stupid. Is it possible to make the table-cell a circle and responsive? I has a display:table-cell in the middle where the logo sits in the center. It is a square cell and I want it round. I tried fiddling with and while it came out good on my browser, when it comes to my mobile device it looks oval.

Here's the css that I used:

```
.tz-header2 .tzlogo a {
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: table-cell;
   width: 200px;
   z-index: 999;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 100%;
   height: 193px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 5px 12px -1px rgba(147,152,153,1);
   -moz-box-shadow: 1px 5px 12px -1px rgba(147,152,153,1);
   box-shadow: 1px 5px 12px -1px rgba(147,152,153,1);
   /* border-style: solid; */
   border-color: whitesmoke;
   background: #d65679;
   }
```

I read somewhere to use width: 100% and height: auto but that made it oval in shape. It wrapped around the img logo. I don't know how to explain it very well. Here's a link of the website to make more sense.

http://1d6.60a.myftpupload.com/

Comment: you want something like responsive square ? it can be turned to circle, by `border-radius:50%`

Comment: The logo for me has a round shape. It's a circle! http://i.imgur.com/o2GfegY.png

Comment: @Deepak I want the circle to stay circle when resizing the web browser or on mobile devices. It shows up like this on my phone http://i.imgur.com/s1P2pgp.png

Comment: @IvankaTodorova the problem is when it's loaded for smaller devices. It gets squished to an oval shape

Comment: removing this css solved the problem .tz-header2 .tzlogo a img {
    width: 100px; /* set this to auto */
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, why you want it to be table-cell, 
But, if you do these following things,you logo stays almost proper circle, in all resolutions

```
.tz-header2 .tzlogo a {
display:block;
line-height:193px; /* height of circle, to vertically align logo in middle Line No: 185 (index.html) */
}
.tz-header2 .tzlogo a img {
width:100% /* keep it 100% for all screen resolutions Line No.: 11983 (style.css) */
}
```

Comment: It is actually a template that I downloaded and I am tweaking it. How come I can't find .tz-header2 .tzlogo a img {.. I feel so dumb right now. But you guys are really helpful! I'm trying all your suggestions right now. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't matters, if you can't find, simply write this code, at the bottom of your CSS, it will work ! and now I have added those line numbers, to edit.

Comment: Hi there sorry for the late reply. I updated the website and it did work but the size when viewed mobile is too big still. I'm trying to figure out how to make it smaller now. http://i.imgur.com/fia7Lss.png

Comment: Use media query and reduce its size on mobile device

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the link. In that, replace `col-md-2-custom` with `col-md-2`

 **OLD**

```
<div class="col-md-2-custom">
   <h3 class="tzlogo">
       <a href="http://1d6.60a.myftpupload.com" title="Emily Grace Events">
          <img src="http://1d6.60a.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/logo-design-GV2-small.png" alt="Emily Grace Events">
        </a>
     </h3>
  </div>
```

**New One :**

```
<div class="col-md-2">
       <h3 class="tzlogo">
           <a href="http://1d6.60a.myftpupload.com" title="Emily Grace Events">
              <img src="http://1d6.60a.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/logo-design-GV2-small.png" alt="Emily Grace Events">
            </a>
         </h3>
      </div>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this! I tried it. And yes it does keep the circle shape but the it doesn't size down when screen is smaller. It keeps the same size and it's covers the slider.

Answer (score 0):

To make something round as a circle, you should have a square. In your case on mobile devices the image has `height` **>** `width`, which causes the logo to be in a oval shape.

To fix this in your media query for smaller screens just make sure the element that wraps the image to have `width` **=** `height`.

First add a class to the `<a>` holding the logo - `logo-wrapper`:

```
<a href="http://1d6.60a.myftpupload.com" title="Emily Grace Events" class="logo-wrapper">
    <img src="http://1d6.60a.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/logo-design-GV2-small.png" alt="Emily Grace Events">
</a>
```

Then in your CSS media query - `@media (max-width: 479px)` add:

```
.logo-wrapper {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

And to center the logo  after the new width is applied:

```
.tz-header2 .tzlogo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -9px 0 0 -50px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In current design do some changes in `.tz-header2 .tzlogo a`. Changes are as below

```
height 100%;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 31%; 
padding-bottom: 26%;
```

and
remove   `line-height: 193px;`